# Tensorflow TFlearn - Random forest regression

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use the TFlearn (nee skflow) TensorForestEstimator to do regression, and it's dumping core when I fit(). In my ForestHParams I'm setting num_classes=0 and regression=True. Would those be the right settings for regression? I'm using Tensorflow 0.10.0

Comment: Changing to num_classes=1 stops the core dump, but now it runs forever.  So I tried adding max_nodes=50, steps=10 to the ForestHParams (small enough values that it should run relatively quickly) and it still runs forever.  TensorForestEstimator itself will not accept a steps parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

num_classes=1 is the right setting.  Also trying passing a random_forest.TensorForestLossMonitor (or maybe called just LossMonitor, depending on the version) in the monitors kwarg of fit().  It will terminate training when the tree grows to max size.  Or, fit() has a max_steps kwargs you can use (it doesn't go in ForestHParams, you just pass it to the function).

Comment: Thanks, that really helped.  I'm training in a reasonable amount of time now with no errors.  One note is that evaluate() for regression returns an r2 key, rather than an accuracy key, which makes sense.